# How to get an GeoExt LegendPanel with image/png instead of image/gif?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I am using a `GeoExt.LegendPanel` to show legends for my various layers in *OpenLayers*. The `GeoExt.WMSLegend` supports configuring which image format to use, but the LegendPanel does not utilize this causing the WMSLegend to fallback to *image/gif*.

So far I have manually edited the *GeoExt.js* minified file to make the WMSLegend use *image/png* as default instead of *image/gif*, but I would prefer to parameterize this.

**Am I missing some way to configure my LegendPanel to use *image/png* as my WMSLegend image format?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a following way:

```
var legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    ...
    map: map,
    defaults: {
        showTitle: false,
        baseParams: {
            FORMAT: 'image/png'
        }
    }
});
```